# I made a USB bootable of backtrack5 using unetbootin. but, no ui appears for installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I made a USB bootable of backtrack5 using unetbootin. but, no ui appears for installation. first UI screen appears for selection for the type of install.In all types of installation selection after selecting the type of install I land on a terminal window.

P.S.: I am having dell inspiron 1525 model, 4gb, core2 duo, 2.40ghz, win7 32 bit installed and system supports 64bit os.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for the backtrack support forum or mailing list.

Comment: that forum is too slow... so, I prefer stackoverflow

Comment: Regardless of the speed of those communities, StackOverflow is a specialized forum for questions related to programming.  Your question is not programming-related, so it is likely that you will not get much of a response and the question may be closed.  If you need faster support, I suggest trying the backtrack IRC channels or working around the issue by using a DVD instead of a flash drive.

Comment: It's landing on terminal, terminal is a sort of programming right ? expecting a command to be entered in that terminal as answer, and I don't want to argue with whether I should have posted this question here or not... may be someone else may help... I have tried on vmware too... problem persists... its not the issue with usb boot.

Comment: got the command it is "startx" insert this command and UI appears :) cheers !!!